# Cognitively Guided Instruction (CGI) for 5th Grade

Tags: course-design, primary-education, course-sequence

Are there any schools out there successfully using CGI with a 5th grade curriculum? Our students have poor number sense, and we'd like to remediate using [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitively_Guided_Instruction). I'd love to compare sequences of lessons with anyone involved in the same endeavor! There are some resources out there, notably, [Children' Mathematics](http://www.heinemann.com/ChildrensMath/) (Carpenter et al), but I am more interested in sharing our first hand experiences.

Comment: Cognitively Guided Instruction. Thanks for the edit, Amir, but I have read Children's Mathematics and it is does not provide scope/sequence advice.

Comment: Sam, in fact it is why I added "I am more interested in sharing our first hand experiences". Also, please consider that what I've written is not an answer to your post. It is just an edit based on my understanding of your question. Thus please feel free to change it in any way that better reflect your question.